# Prove limit is zero $A_n = \frac{(1/3)(1/3+1)\dots(1/3 + (n-1))}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I came across this sequence $A_n$ while studying the convergence of the Maclaurin series of this function

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}}$$

When I write down the Maclaurin series, it turns out it's absolutely convergent for $|x|\lt1$

OK... But what happens at $x=\pm1$? I think at these two points the Maclaurin series turns into an alternating number series. To prove these two series (for $x=\pm1)$ are convergent, I need to show that the following sequence **goes to zero** and use the Leibniz criterion.

$$A_n = \frac{(1/3)(1/3+1)\dots(1/3 + (n-1))}{n!}$$

But I think I have no idea how to do it.

I see the sequence decreases but how do I show it goes to zero?
I think there should be simple trick to prove that the limit of this sequence is zero.

Maybe I need to show $A_n < 1/\ln(n)$ or something like that, not sure?!

Comment: You have to show $A_n$ *decreases monotonically* to $0$ from a certain point.

Comment: @Gary ... which is quite clear when you take the $\log$ (see my answer below)

Comment: @Gary It's obviously decreasing, that's not a problem. $A_{n+1} = A_n \cdot B(n)$ where $B(n) \lt 1$

Comment: I am just saying that it is also part of the criteria in the Leibniz test.

Comment: @Gary Yes... that's correct.

Comment: Just for your interest: $$
A_n  \sim \frac{1}{{\Gamma (1/3)}}\frac{1}{{n^{2/3} }}
$$ for large $n$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2062261/253273)

Comment: Theorem. If every $a_n\in [0,1)$ then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=0\iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has
$$\log(A_n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log \left( \frac{\frac{1}{3} + k}{k+1}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log \left( \frac{3k+1}{3k+3}\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log \left( 1-\frac{2}{3k+3}\right) $$

Now,
$$\log\left( 1-\frac{2}{3k+3}\right) \sim - \frac{2}{3k+3}$$

which is the general term of a divergent series. Hence, by comparison, the series $\displaystyle{\sum \log \left( 1-\frac{2}{3k+3}\right) }$ is also divergent, and because it has negative terms, you get that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \log \left( 1-\frac{2}{3k+3}\right) = - \infty$$

or equivalently,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \log(A_n) = -\infty$$

which leads directly to
$$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} A_n = 0}$$

Comment: I don't quite follow but I think I was able to show by induction that $A_n \lt 1/\ln{n}$

Comment: @peter.petrov Which part don't you understand ?

Comment: Need to reread it and rethink it... NP. thanks for the idea.

Comment: I think I kind of understand your solution, thanks again. What exactly does the $\sim$ mean there?

Comment: @peter.petrov "$u_n \sim v_n$" means that the two sequences are equivalent, in the sense that $u_n / v_n$ tends to $1$. In particular, for positive (or negative) sequences, this implies that the series $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ both converge or both diverge. This is what I use here. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) for more details.

Comment: OK... I see now what the symbol means. And to prove that we can use L'Hôpital's rule, right?

Comment: OK... I see, thanks.

Comment: @peter.petrov Indeed, what I used is the equivalent $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ when $x$ tends to $0$, i.e. the fact that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$$ which can be proved using l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prove by induction that

$$A_n \lt \frac{1}{\ln{n}} \tag{***}$$

for all $n \ge 6$

The tricky part is to start the induction at $n=6$ (the base case of the induction) so that the induction step can be done smoothly later on.

The rest of the induction follows in a pretty straightforward way. We assume that the inequality is true for some $n \ge 6$, and we prove it for $n+1$ using the assumption we have for $n$.

The only thing I use is that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \lt 3$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

In fact $(***)$ is also true for $n = 2,3,4,5$ but it seems one has to check these cases separately one by one.

From that inequality $(***)$ and since $A_n \gt 0$, it follows easily that $${\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} A_n = 0}$$