# Spivak, Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", Problem 21c

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following problem is from Chapter 23 "Infinite Series" of Spivak's *Calculus*. Note that there are questions about convergence of the binomial series such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062261/binomial-series-convergence), but the current question concerns a specific proof. Namely, the one presented in the problem below.

> 21. In this problem we will establish the "binomial
>     series"
>
> $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k, |x|<1$$
>
> for any $\alpha$, by showing that $R_{n,0}(x)=0$. The proof is in
> several steps, and uses the Cauchy and Lagrange forms as found in
> problem 10-21.
>
> (a) Use the ratio test to show that the series
> $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} r^k$ does indeed converge for  > $|r|<1$.
>
> (b) Suppose first that $0\leq x<1$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}
>  R_{n,0}(x)=0$, but using Lagrange's form of the remainder, noticing
> that $(1+t)^{\alpha-n-1}\leq 1$ for $n+1>\alpha$.
>
> (c) Now suppose that $-1<x<0$; the number $t$ in Cauchy's form of the
> remainder satisfies $-1<x_t\leq 0$. Show that
>
> $$|x(1+t)^{\alpha-1}|\leq |x|M, \text{ where }
>  M=\max(1,(1+x)^{\alpha-1}),$$
>
> and
>
> $$\left | \frac{x-t}{1+t} \right |=|x|\left ( \frac{1-t/x}{1+t} \right
>  )\leq |x|\tag{1}$$
>
> Using Cauchy's form of the remainder, and the fact that
>
> $$(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1} = \alpha \binom{\alpha-1}{n}$$
>
> show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} R_{n,0}(x)=0$

I was able to prove (a) and (b) and most of (c), up to (1). The issue is proving the last part, namely that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} R_{n,0}(x)=0$.

The solution manual has the following

> $$|R_{n,0}(0)|=\left | (n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}x(1+t)^{\alpha-1} \left(\frac{x-t}{1+t}\right )^n \right |\tag{2}$$
> $$\leq |x\alpha M|\cdot \left |\binom{\alpha-1}{n}x^n\right | \to 0
>  \text{ by part } a$$

First off, the $R_{n,0}(0)$ seems to be a typo. This would be the n-th order remainder evaluated at $0$.

What I have is the following

$$R_{n,0}(x)=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}(1+t)^{\alpha-(n+1)}x^{n+1}$$

$$=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\cdot x\cdot (1+t)^{\alpha-1}\cdot \left ( \frac{x}{1+t}\right )^n$$

How is (2) obtained?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^\alpha$, $\alpha\neq0$.
Part (a) of the exercise (presumably solved)  implies that $\sum_n\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$ converges for all $|x|<1$. The implies  that $\lim_{n\rightarrow}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n=0$ for all  each $x$ with $|x|<1$.

Notice that
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\alpha\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha-n+1)(1+x)^{\alpha-n}=n!\binom{\alpha}{n}(1+x)^{\alpha-n}$$

---

(c) The residue in the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x_0=0$ in Cauchy's form is
$$R_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi)(x-\xi)^n x=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-n-1}(x-\xi)^nx$$
where $\xi=\xi_{x, n}$ is between $x$ and $0$.

If $-1<x<0$, then $-1<x<\xi<0$ and so
$$0<\frac{\xi-x}{1+\xi}<-x=|x|$$
since $\phi(\xi)=\frac{\xi-x}{1+\xi}=1-\frac{x+1}{1+\xi}$ increases on $(-1,\infty)$. Indeed, $\phi'(\xi)=\frac{1+x}{(1+\xi)^2}>0$; hence $\phi(\xi)<\phi(0)=-x$ for all $x<\xi<0$. Consequently,
$$|R_n(x)|<\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\Big||x|^{n+1}(1+\xi_{x,n})^{\alpha-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
since $0<1+x<|1+\xi_{x,n}|<1$.

---

(b) The remainder in the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x_0=0$ in Lagrange's form is
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} x^n=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-n-1}x^{n+1}$$
where $\xi=\xi_{x, n}$ is between  $0$ and  $x$.

Therefore, for $0<x<1$, $0<\xi<x$ and so,
$$|R_n(x)|\leq\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n+1}x^{n+1}\Big|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

---

Although not part of the questions mentioned in the OP, it is interesting determine when  $\sum_n\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n}\Big|$ converges.

Notice that for $n>\lfloor \alpha\rfloor$
$$n\Big(\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}-1\Big)=n\Big(\frac{n-\alpha}{n+1}-1\Big)=\frac{n}{n+1}(-\alpha-1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-\alpha-1$$
From Raabe's theorem, it follows that if $\alpha>0$, $-\alpha-1<-1$ and so the series $\sum_n\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n}\Big|<\infty$; whereas if $\alpha<0$, $-1-\alpha>-1$ in which case, $\sum_n\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n}\Big|=\infty$.