# Spivak, Ch. 24, Problem 7

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

> 7. In this problem we deduce the binomial series $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n, |x|<1$$
>
> without all the work of Problem 23-21, although we will use a fact
> established in part (a) of that problem - the series
> $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n$ does converge
> for $|x|<1$.
>
> (a) Prove that $(1+x)f'(x)=\alpha f(x)$ for $|x|<1$.

I've asked about 23-21 before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572392/spivak-ch-23-infinite-series-problem-21c) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572188/spivak-calculus-problem-21a-what-does-spivak-mean-with-binomnk-and-k).

The solution manual has the following as the solution to (a)

$$(1+x)f'(x)=(1+x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n\binom{\alpha}{n}x^{n-1}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left [n\binom{\alpha}{n}+(n+1) \binom{\alpha}{n+1}\right ] x^n$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \alpha \binom{\alpha}{n}x^n=\alpha f(x)$$

Let me try to go through what is happening here

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^{n-1}$$

$$(1+x)f'(x)=(1+x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^{n-1}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}nx^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n} nx^n$$

Now

$$\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}\cdot \frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha-n}\frac{n+1}{n+1}$$

$$=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{\alpha-n}$$

and so

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}nx^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{\alpha-n}nx^{n-1}$$

I'm not sure what manipulations are necessary at this point. It appears, from the solution manual solution, that this would need to be equal to

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}x^n$$

Comment: These are problems from Spivak's Calculus. They are each independent problems. Each problem provides one particular proof. Sometimes problems use results from previous problems. That's why I linked to my previous questions: the current problem statement mentions the questions in those problems. 

I am simply trying to understand how to solve the solution manual solution to this problem 7.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I've spent over 1000 hours on this book. 2 hours on this particular item of this problem. I always read the solution manual after I have solved the problem, except if I really can't solve it like this problem. Also, this isn't an interesting problem, it is simply manipulation of an expression. You assume too much with your previous comment.

Comment: But since you ventured to assume, let me tell you my impression of your contributions. You seem not to read the questions I spend quite a bit of time and effort to write in the best way possible. You assume they are related (and then proceed to vote to close them sometimes).

Comment: Integrating factors and other techniques for solving differential equations have not been introduced in this book so far. That is precisely the point of the question. It is based on manipulation of the summations. This is why the solution manual solution is included. Does it look to you like they solved a differential equation?

Comment: I understand your frustration, but please don't act passive-aggressive towards another user. Someone with more rep than me should understand that. They were just trying to understand what your motivation was. Sure, maybe they misunderstood the post, but honestly, it was difficult for me (and probably other people) to understand what you were doing.

Comment: @Accelerator if you met me you would know that if I want to be aggressive I am only active-aggressive. The insinuation by the other user that I am merely following solution manuals is an incorrect assumption, as I said directly without any hesitation. I am not frustrated with anything related to math by the way. When people assume, well, perhaps you know the saying. And that is the only frustrating part: the type of interaction that occurs on this site sometimes where people assume things about others and say things that are uncalled-for.

Comment: @Accelerator Would appreciate if you would take back the accusation of passive-aggressiveness. This term has no place in my actions here or in life in general.

Comment: Note that there was in fact something missing in the original post. I originally wrote the preamble of the question but not the actual item (a). It is there now. That is the thing that is being proved by the solution manual.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the identities
\begin{align}
(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}&=\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}{n}\tag{1}\label{one}\\
\binom{\alpha-1}{n}+\binom{\alpha-1}{n-1}&=\binom{\alpha}{n}\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
For then,
$$f'(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}n\binom{\alpha}{n}x^{n-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}x^n=\alpha\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha-1}{n} x^n$$
Hence
\begin{align}
(1+x)f'(x)&=\alpha\,(1+x)\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha-1}{n}x^n
=\alpha\left(\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha-1}{n}x^n+\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha-1}{n}x^{n+1}\right)\\
&=\alpha\left(1+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\binom{\alpha-1}{n}+\binom{\alpha-1}{n-1}\Big)x^n\right)\\
&=\alpha\Big(1+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n\Big)=\alpha\sum^n_{n=0}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n=\alpha f(x)
\end{align}

Thus, $f$ satisfies in $(-1,1)$ the (differential) equation
$$(1+x)f'(x)-\alpha f(x)=0$$
with $f(0)=\binom{\alpha}{0}=1$. To prove the identity of interest, lets compare $(1+x)^\alpha$ and $f(x)$ as follows: define
$$g(x):=\frac{f(x)}{(1+x)^\alpha}=(1+x)^{-\alpha}f(x)$$
Then
$$g'(x)=-\alpha(1+x)^{-1-\alpha}f(x)+(1+x)^\alpha f'(x)=-(1+\alpha)^{-\alpha-1}\Big((1+x)f'(x)-\alpha f(x)\Big)=0$$
This means that $g$ is constant on $(-1,1)$. Evaluating at $x=0$ yields
$g(0)=1$; hence $g(x)=(1+x)^{-\alpha}f(x)\equiv1$,

---

Here is a proof of \eqref{one}

\begin{align}
(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}&=(n+1)\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha-(n+1)+1)}{(n+1)!}\\
&=\alpha\frac{(\alpha-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha-1-n+1)}{n!}\\
&=\alpha\binom{\alpha}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not too sure about expression (1). My calculations have been telling me otherwise, and I just checked in Maple and it says false as well.

Comment: @evianpring: The proof can be done with pencil and paper. I added one in my posting.

Comment: @evianpring: forgot to press the save changes...anyway, there you go; your computations in Maple are wrong, write a simple code in C  (or Maple if that is what you use) to compute binomial factors. To be more efficient, use some numerical recipes (factorials are expensive and are better approximated by gamma functions).

Answer (score 0):

In the original post, the equation

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^{n-1}\tag{2}$$

is incorrect because the index $n$ starts at $1$. It should be

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^{n-1}\tag{3}$$

In fact, I copied the solution manual incorrectly: in equation (1) I wrote the summation with $n=0$ originally but it is actually written $n=1$ in the solution manual (fixed now).

This is the crucial point because it means we can rewrite the equation as

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n+1} (n+1)x^{n}$$

Now,

$$(1+x)f'(x)=(1+x)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^{n-1}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}nx^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^n$$

Note that the second term can be rewritten as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^n$ because it is $0$ for $n=0$. Thus

$$(1+x)f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n+1} (n+1)x^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} nx^n$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [(n+1) \binom{\alpha}{n+1}+n\binom{\alpha}{n}\right ]\tag{1b}$$

So now only the final step from the solution manual is left. Of course, it is actually many steps, as we will now see.

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [\alpha (n+1)\binom{\alpha-1}{n+1}+n\binom{\alpha}{n}\right ]$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [\alpha n\binom{\alpha-1}{n+1}+\alpha n\binom{\alpha-1}{n}+\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}{n+1}\right ]$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [ \alpha n\binom{\alpha}{n+1} +\binom{\alpha}{n+1} \right ]$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [ \binom{\alpha}{n+1}\alpha(1+n) \right ]$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left [ \binom{\alpha}{n}\alpha \right ]$$

$$=\alpha \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n \binom{\alpha}{n}$$

$$=\alpha f(x)$$

This is the type of problem in Spivak for which I will gladly look at the solution manual. The insights to solve this aren't interesting. It is just algebraic manipulation. A little nudge from the solution manual only optimizes the learning process.